# PHP how to remove the html tags(<DIV></DIV>,<P></P>,<SPAN></SPAN>) from the string

Tags: php

Am using the strip_tags() to remove the HTML tags from one content . but i wants to remove the html (`<DIV></DIV>,<P></P>,<SPAN></SPAN>`) tags apart from the `<img>` tag and `<a>` , i don't want to remove the `<img ><a>` tag from that . but need to remove other all html tags from that content how can i do help me.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to strip all tags except for `<img>` tag, you can do like this:

```
strip_tags($your_text, '<img><a>');
```

The second parameter of the `strip_tags` function allows you to specify the allowed tags. You can specify more than one tags too.

Comment: I think `strip_tags($text, '<a><img>')` is what Dam wants. Also, here's the documentation for `strip_tags`: http://php.net/strip_tags +1

Comment: @Felix: yes you are right, he added this after i posted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><img>sdfsdfsdfsd</img><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo "\n";
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a><img>');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`strip_tags` has a lot of edge cases where it doesn't work. If you are using this on untrusted content, you'd be better off using [HtmlPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) instead.